# Computer can read disk but can't boot from it

Tags: ubuntu, boot, disk-drive

I'm having trouble booting from a CD on my laptop. It's able to read the CD once the computer has booted into the OS on the hard drive, but when I choose the disk drive option from the boot menu, it won't boot into the CD. I've tried multiple CDs, all of which are bootable and that I was able to boot into on another computer.

If it makes a difference, the OS installed on the laptop is Ubuntu.

Comment: You are not missing those 5 secs to press any key to continue with booting from CD/DVD, are not you? What do the BIOS boot priority currently you have in there?

Comment: CD is first in the boot order

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason is that in Your bios fast bios mode is enabled. Try disabling this and check if you can boot from CD.

Comment: No, it's not set to fast BIOS

Answer (score 0):

I changed the boot mode from UEFI to CSM and was able to boot from the CD